# Where is the date picker in WinRT XAML?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I see the date picker control in WinRT JavaScript/HTML5. Where is that control for XAML?

Comment: Actually the built-in control is not a datepicker, but rather 3 comboboxes. It is easy to do the same with XAML.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "easy", when you consider all of the different cultures and their respective date systems, much less all of the different methods of doing things like DST. The 8.1 date picker handles these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Win 8.1 includes built-in XAML controls for DatePicker, TimePicker.  So if you retarget your project to target Win 8.1 you will now get these controls.

retargeting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263114.aspx

Answer (score 4):

There is no date picker control in the standard Windows 8.0 toolbox. However, look at the Callisto for many handy WinRT XAML controls, including the date picker control. https://github.com/timheuer/Callisto

Comment: Actually, the Callisto date picker is incomplete

Comment: So, what did you use? Have you found good and _free_ DatePicker?

Comment: God, I just fought this *this* last weekend writing my app. I ended up writing my own. I was very mad when I got done. This should be like control #1 from MSFT. When has the .NET framework ever shipped without this type of control "out of the box" except just now? </fail>

Comment: As of June 2013, the Callisto toolkit still doesn't have a WinRT DatePicker.  However, Jason Mitchell has written a DatePicker control which is available in NuGet.  Here's a link to his blog: http://jason-mitchell.com/windows-8/datepicker-for-c-xaml-windows-store-apps/

Answer (score 4):

The best one I've found (complete with templating and xaml friendly formatting options) is:

https://github.com/jasonmitchell/WinRT-XAML-DatePicker

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect our [package](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Windows8-UI-Controls.aspx) of WinRT components. It contains date picker component as well as a lot of other UI components: radial and plain menus, color picker, rating controls and so on. And it's totally free btw ;).

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there isn't a official control for datetime picker in XAML. but it seem that microsoft will be coming up with one in the future. [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/winappswithcsharp/thread/28515145-d7ef-4625-bca4-6e45c2350cf6)

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion's WinRT Studio (Beta) includes a very, very good DatePicker and it's free to use.

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt

Comment: It's free to use for 1 month.

Comment: Because it's not in beta anymore. I still am using the beta version for free.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the following control that looks like the same as the javascript one:
https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/25356#181302.