# DATEPICKER Control In Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the date picker in WinRT XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965877/where-is-the-date-picker-in-winrt-xaml)

I need a DATEPICKER control for my Metro App . I checked the toolbox and unable to find one.
I Searched on Google but there are paid versions from Telerik , I can't use the trial control as it would be rejected in the marketplace .
Need help

Comment: Might be !! Sorry I didn't check

Comment: http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/winrt-calendar--date-picker

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, this is going to be an answer you don't like, but it's the answer.

In Windows Phone there is a Windows Phone Toolkit with many more XAML controls than what ship with the SDK. There is no such toolkit with Windows 8.

With a simple internet search you might find the [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/).  This is a great resource, not from Microsoft, but also does not include a date picker.

You might also stumble across the [WinRT XAML Calendar](http://winrtxamlcalendar.codeplex.com/). This is a port from the Silverlight calendar. And, it's nice. But not a picker.

Another excellent free resource is the [Callisto Toolkit](http://timheuer.github.com/callisto/) by Tim Heuer, from Microsoft. This solves many problems (like settings and flyouts) but not date picker.

In a recent DevRadio podcast interview (we haven't released that episode yet) with Tim Heuer I asked him if the date picker was on the way in Callisto and he said *maybe*. The reason is, localizing a date picker is a real pain because around the world dates are not handled exactly the same. This barrier to an enthusiast to build a custom date picker is significant. And it's why you aren't finding a free one out there yet.

I imagine there will be a free date picker popping up soon. And, to be honest, I am surprised I have not seen one yet. It just speaks to the complexity of the task. You are not the first to ask this question [Where is the date picker in WinRT XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965877/where-is-the-date-picker-in-winrt-xaml) ( :) I was! )

Having said all that, I think this warrants a justification to those paid-for third party components that get the job done correctly, completely, and (often) beautifully. Let's see what our choices are:

1. Component One ([here](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/DateTimeEditorsXAML/)) $395
2. Telerik ([here](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-8/controls/date-picker.aspx)) $199
3. Infragistics ([here](http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-ui/)) beta
4. Perpetuum ([here](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Product.aspx?lang=en&pid=150&tid=overview)) $99
5. DevExpress ([here](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinRT/Editors/)) $499
6. ComponentArt (none)

So, it still might tempt you to write your own. That's okay, too. If you have a constrained list of supported cultures than you can do it. And, reviewing how some of those in the list above look - that will get you far. If you do a great job, share the wealth and put it on CodePlex.

Comment: Do you really want me to mark that as an answer :-P:-P:-P .